# QGIS 2.18.13-- the plug in manager only displays 16 possible downloadable plug ins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

This, of course, can't be. The biggest and most pressing one is the processing plugin-- I can't access any of the vector processing tools.
I recently upgraded to 2.18.13, which was released only a few days ago, can that be the issue?

Comment: I should also point out that my Python interpreter isn't working in QGIS either. I get this error: 
Couldn't load QGIS utils.
Python support will be disabled. I guess the processing plugin is a python plugin and therefore not showing up?

Comment: Yes, broken python disables most plugins and processing too. The solution depends on your OS, and whether you have installed python 2 or python 3 elsewhere in your system.

Comment: BTW, if it's useful to anyone, the workaround solution I came up with was to uninstall python and qgis and re-download from this site: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ instead of the QGIS site. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if it's useful to anyone, the workaround solution I came up with was to uninstall python and qgis and re-download from this site: trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w instead of the QGIS site. I hope it helps